# Is any sequence bounded in $W^{1,p}$ if it is bounded in $W^{2,p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose $U$ is an open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary and consider the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}(U)$ consisting of all locally summable functions $u:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for each multi-index $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$, $D^\alpha u$ exists in the weak sense and belongs to the Lebesgue space $L^p(U)$. If $u\in W^{k,p}(U)$, we define its norm to be
$$\Vert u\Vert_{W^{k,p}\ (U)}=\begin{cases}
\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\int_U|D^\alpha u|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p}&,1\leq p<\infty,\\
\sum_{|\alpha|\leq k}\mathrm{ess\ sup}_U|D^\alpha u|&,p=\infty.
\end{cases}$$
With this norm, the Sobolev space can be seen as a metric space, and I'd like to know **whether or not a bounded sequence $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $W^{2,p}(U)$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$**.

I have no intention to take care of $p=\infty$. Only the case $1\leq p<\infty$ is what I really care about. If we write
$$\Vert u_n\Vert_{W^{2,p}\ (U)}=\left(\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1}\int_U|D^\alpha u_n|^p+\sum_{|\alpha|=2}\int_U|D^\alpha u_n|^p\right)^\frac{1}{p},$$
and note that each integral is non-negative, can we conclude that $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$? Thank you.

FYI, I was thinking about applying the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem to a bounded sequence in $W^{2,p}(U)$, but before that, I think it necessary to check if this sequence is bounded in $W^{1,p}(U)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$||u||_{W^{1,p}(U)} \leq ||u||_{W^{2,p}(U)}$$

For any $p,U$ and $u \in W^{2,p}(U)$

This completely solves the question

Comment: How does this inequality come about? Thank you.

Comment: You just said it in the question, (when $p < \infty$) it comes from the fact that $\sum_{|\alpha| = 2}{ \int_{U}{ |D^\alpha u|^p dx}} \geq 0$, when $p = \infty$ it's similar

Comment: Moreover whenever $r > k$ you have
$||u||_{W^{k,p}(U)} \leq ||u||_{W^{r,p}(U)}$ and no hypothesis is needed